# What is the last day of this year's Winter Bash?

Tags: discussion

In order to acquire the Philantropist Hat, you have to award a bounty on the last day.  Since all the Hats disappear on January 2nd does that mean the last day is Wednesday, January 1st?

Because my time zone is GMT which is about 7 (or is it 8?) hours before the U.S.A. does that then mean I would have to wait till at least 8 a.m. here in the U.K. on Wednesday, January 1st, for the award to count?

The exact time is important to ensure the bounty does not expire before the last day of the Winter Bash.

Comment: Congratulations : You have been awarded the [2019 Erethism Badge](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erethism) for your dedication to hats, millinery and hattery.

Comment: Guilty as charged!  I blame it on the fact there have been only 7 hours and 2 minutes of daylight over the past four days here in the Scottish borders. But tomorrow, December 24th, we are on the turn - we get 7 hours and 3 minutes daylight and by Tuesday 31st it will be 7 hours and 8 minutes.  Yippee!!!  Anyway, what I need to cheer me up is that Philantropist Hat - so what is the last day of the "Winter Bash"?

Comment: The [Oxford English Dictionary](https://www.oed.com/noresults?browseType=sortAlpha&noresults=true&page=1&pageSize=20&q=philantropist&scope=ENTRY&sort=entry&type=dictionarysearch) has no listing for "philantropist". I assume it is a muckstake.

Comment: Yeah, I sondered about that as well.  I thought it was 'philanthropist' but what do I know?  Perhaps we need the American English Dictionary?  Hope nobody takes offence since none is intended (:

Comment: Not in Merriam Webster either.

Comment: You are all a lovable bunch of Christians. Merry Christmas to all. May all hatters have a great New Year also . *Signed: Not the Scrooge!*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**The hats get put back in their boxes on January 2nd!**

Thus the winter bash is over January 1st at midnight of January 1st/2nd UTC Time.

> Coordinated Universal Time (or UTC) is the primary time standard by which the world regulates clocks and time. It is within about 1 second of mean solar time at 0° longitude, and is not adjusted for daylight saving time. In some countries, the term Greenwich Mean Time is used. - [Coordinated Universal Time](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time)

In any case: Merry Christmas to all and to all a good night.

Comment: Very helpful. I will be sure to get my act together in good time. Peace and joy to you and yours and goodwill to all.